# Regex group re-structuring

Tags: regex

I have input data as following as:

```
AB
AB_Test
AB_Test123
```

Expected output:

```
AB
AB_Test
```

I have regex which matches:

```
    ([A-Z]{2})(_([a-zA-Z]*))?
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/69S4H2djl6GBxM3z)

So from above regex, I get the strings in $1 & $3. I want to modify the regex such that the strings will be in $1 & $2 (omit group 2 from above regex).

Now I want to process the matched strings using the group. That is why I want it to be in sequence.

Is there are way by which we can change the above regex?

Comment: Try `(([A-Z]{2})_?[a-zA-Z]*)` Is this what are you looking for? [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/mG3eL5/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to eliminate the strings that have digits, use a negative lookahead assertion:

```
^([A-Z]{2})(?!.*\d.*)(?:_([A-Za-z]*))?
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/kF2vM4/1)

Or add anchors on both ends of the string:

```
^([A-Z]{2})(?:_([A-Za-z]*))?$
```

[Demo 2](http://regex101.com/r/qA2nC9/1)

If you use anchors, you will need to use the `m` flag if you have a multiline target.

Comment: That is a great demo site.  I had not seen it before.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a non-capturing group for the one you don't want:

`^([A-Z]{2})(?:_([a-zA-Z]*))?$`

EDIT: I also added beginning and ending anchors because it seems that you want to match the line only if the characters after the underscore are all letters.

Comment: I worked: https://www.debuggex.com/r/rqVUMw4pxoj56Egr. Will accept your answer. Thanks..

Comment: @Ambrish are you getting the expected output as mentioned in your post?

Comment: Position of `*` is incorrect in the group `([a-zA-Z])*)`. It should be inside the group.

Comment: @Ambrish: You're right. I was just using what you had originally, but it was incorrect. It's fixed now.